# Increasing time difference between data points

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that increases the time between data points as part of automatic data processing, but it currently takes way too long.

One of my sensors logs a data point every 10 seconds, I want to increase this dt to 1 hour. For this I wrote some very simple (inefficient) code (see below) that does work but takes 10-40 minutes to process 1 week of data which is far from ideal.

I've seen recommendations for semi-similar issues to use an array, however I have 0 experience with this and don't know if it's applicable to this goal.

```
    Do While Cells(row + 1, 2).Value <> ""
        If Cells(row + 1, 2).Value - Cells(row, 2).Value < 1 / 24.05 Then
            Rows(row + 1).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            row = row + 1
        End If

    Loop
```

EDIT:

I solved my issue with a slightly edited version of @Damian's code as shown below.

```
Sub Change_dt()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    Dim target As Single
    target = Sheets("Controller").Cells(16, 9).Value
    Dim arrSource As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw data")
        arrSource = .UsedRange.Value 'this will input the whole used sheet inside the array

        Dim finalArr As Variant
        ReDim finalArr(1 To UBound(arrSource), 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2))

        .Cells.Delete 'will clean the worksheet

        Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long, Z As Long
        x = 1
        Z = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrSource)
            On Error Resume Next
            If arrSource(i + Z, 1) = vbNullString Or i = UBound(arrSource) Then Exit For 'will end  the loop once the next row is empty
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If the next row substracted the first is greater than target both will be copied to the final array
            If arrSource(i + Z, 1) - arrSource(i, 1) > target Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2)
                    finalArr(x, j) = arrSource(i, j)
                    finalArr(x + 1, j) = arrSource(i + Z, j)
                Next j
                x = x + 2 'increment 2 on x because you wrote 2 lines
                i = i + Z
                Z = 1
            Else
                Z = Z + 1
            End If

        Next i

        'paste the resulting array back to the sheet
        .Range("A1", .Cells(UBound(finalArr), UBound(finalArr, 2))).Value = finalArr

        'eliminate the extra unused rows
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        .Rows(i & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete

    End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help a lot in your executing time:

```
Sub Change_dt()
    Dim target As Single
    target = Sheets("Controller").Cells(16, 9).Value
    Dim arrSource As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw data")
        arrSource = .UsedRange.Value 'this will input the whole used sheet inside the array

        Dim finalArr As Variant
        ReDim finalArr(1 To UBound(arrSource), 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2))

        .Cells.Delete 'will clean the worksheet

        Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long
        x = 1
        For i = 5 To UBound(arrSource)
            On Error Resume Next
            If arrSource(i + 1, 2) = vbNullString Or i = UBound(arrSource) Then Exit For 'will end  the loop once the next row is empty
            On Error GoTo 0
            'If the next row substracted the first is greater than 1/24.05 both will be copied to the final array
            If Not arrSource(i + 1, 2) - arrSource(i, 2) < target Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2)
                    finalArr(x, j) = arrSource(i, j)
                    finalArr(x + 1, j) = arrSource(i + 1, j)
                Next j
                x = x + 2 'increment 2 on x because you wrote 2 lines
            End If

        Next i

        'paste the resulting array back to the sheet
        .Range("A1", .Cells(UBound(finalArr), UBound(finalArr, 2))).Value = finalArr

        'eliminate the extra unused rows
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        .Rows(i & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do a .clearcontents on the row and then sort, instead of deleting the row, it will be even faster.

Comment: @Warcupine I do not delete any rows, delete the whole `Sheet.Cells` and paste an array back.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Running the code gives me a compile error ("Invalid Next control variable reference")  on this part: 
` If i = 1 Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                finalArr(x, j) = arrSource(i, j)
            Next i
            x = x + 1 `

Comment: sorry @BartPostma a little mistake, the first `next i` after the `for j` is a `next j`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Damian , now I get a compile error on the final 'Next i' saying "Next without for". No clue why as I can see the 'for' quite clearly.

Apologies for being a massive noob.

Comment: jesus... I did a lot of wrong on that code... Tested now, no compile errors. Check my edited answer @BartPostma

Comment: No errors this time @Damian but it just deleted all the content of the sheet (including headers. I'm afraid I'm still incapable of properly understanding how an array works but I feel like our approach is inherently wrong. The time difference between each following point is 10 seconds, so the condition (time difference of ~1 hour) will never be met without deleting rows. Would it help if I send the excel file with some data?

Comment: Or a screen, does your first row start with blanks? the macro will exit the loop when finding a blank cell on column B, so starting from A1, if B2 is blank the macro will automatically stop the loop and paste a blank array.

Comment: So your data starts on row 7? or did you add a row to show me that "Below this cell"?

Comment: It starts on row 7 yes

Comment: It deleted everything again and gave a subscript out of range error on finalArr(x, j) = arrSource(i, j)

Comment: Can you send me a sample of your data via onedrive or something like that? So i can test it.

Comment: File I use: 
<https://www.dropbox.com/s/bymix5jskivadox/Timestep.xlsm?dl=0>
Raw data (only use channel 0 and 1):
<https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5d0i9f493z5npw/BlueVis_Export.csv?dl=0>

Comment: Strange both work without logging in for me, how about this one: https://www89.zippyshare.com/v/cvpZVt1R/file.html 
@Damian sorry for the issues

Comment: Neither... it might be my company proxy... Can't you upload it to google drive?

Comment: Only people within my company can open my onedrive links I'm afraid. If you mail me at [removed company mail] I'll mail you the files?

Comment: Disregard that first mail, use bapo224@hotmail.nl if you're willing to make your mail known to me.

Comment: Will try to download the files from home this afternoon then

Comment: @BartPostma ok now this works on your workbook, leaves about 7,5k of rows from the 43k in barely seconds. Try the edited code :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort @Damian. It's close to working how I'd want it but it still deletes headers and keeps dt too small (8 mins when I set it to 1 hour), but I don't want to bother you even more.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, with some tweaking I got it to work the way I wanted it to! It's not just 100 times faster as I'd anticipated, it's more like 1000 times faster so I'm very happy with the result.

Comment: Glad it could help... Try understanding about the arrays, and look forward use them with dictionaries. When handling large sets of data, they are the way to go ;) @BartPostma